# Parallax scrolling effect, start at certain percentage on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using this script to create a parallax scroll effect on my page:

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    parallax();
});

function parallax() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.cloud1').css('top', - (scrolled * 0.1) + '%');
    $('.cloud2').css('top', - (scrolled * 0.3) + '%');
    $('.cloud3').css('top', - (scrolled * 0.2) + '%');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cloud1"></div>
<div class="cloud2"></div>
<div class="cloud3"></div>
```

**CSS** (same for `.cloud2` and `.cloud3` but with different background image, opacity and 'top' 'left'):

```
.cloud1 {
   background: url(../images/cloud1.png) no-repeat;
   opacity: 0.9;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 50%;
   left: 20%;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

When the script begins (on scroll) the **HTML** changes to this:

```
<div class="cloud1" style="top: 0%; "></div>
```

which makes the 'cloud' jump to the top of the page, and then the parallax starts (which you can see for a very short period of time as it's already jumped to the top of the page)

Is there a way to set the `style="top: 0%;"` to start at say 20% when the parallax begins, and then begin to multiply by 0.1?

Here is a codepen of the problem : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tkfDH

Hopefully this is clear,

Any help is appreciated

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I think i've fixed the problem.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
 parallax();
});
function parallax(){
  var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('.cloud1').css('top', -(scrolled*0.1)+70+'%'); 
// the 70 corresponds to the 'cloud1' value for 'top'.

    $('.cloud2').css('top', -(scrolled*0.3)+50+'%');
// the 50 corresponds to the 'cloud2' value for 'top'.
}
```

http://cdpn.io/naIjf

```
#hero {
background:black; 
    color: white;
}

.cloud1, .cloud2 {
    opacity: 0.8;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cloud1 {
    background: url('http://www.jrk-design.co.uk/v2/images/big-cloud.png') no-repeat;
top: 70%;
left: 0;
}

.cloud2 {
background: url('http://www.jrk-design.co.uk/v2/images/big-cloud.png') no-repeat;
top: 50%;
left: 65%;
}
```

Fixed the jump.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to solve my problem, would have been great if their was a way to write something like `$('.cloud1').css('top' = 50%, - (scrolled * 0.1) + '%');` or something in the script - alas this works and is quite a neat solution, thanks for your help!

Comment: I originally had that idea, adding = won't work, so i've modified it so that each cloud has their 'top' value added to the jQuery. It works even without a jump!